# Entity Framework - Link Table Name Issue

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have a table called "Articles" and then a linking table called "RelatedArticles".

The RelatedArticles table simply maps an article to another article. Entity Framework is looking for the table "ArticleArticles". What can I put in the OnModelCreating method that tells Entity Framework the actual name of this linking table?

```
Table RelatedArticles {
    int articleId
    int relatedArticleId
}
```

There is no class "RelatedArticles". Only a List property in the class Article:

```
public class Article
{
    public Article()
    {
        Links = new HashSet<Link>();
        RelatedArticles = new HashSet<Article>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime Created { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Link> Links { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Article> RelatedArticles { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I answered and then realized that you may not be doing what I thought you were.  Can you show the actual C# classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override `OnModelCreating` to specify the table and column names:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Article>()
        .HasMany(a => a.RelatedArticles)
        .WithMany()
        .Map(t => t.MapLeftKey("articleId")
            .MapRightKey("relatedArticleId")
            .ToTable("RelatedArticles"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If it were a class you could use the attribute `[Table(Name = "RelatedArticles"]`.  See [the docs about TableAttribute on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.mapping.tableattribute(v=vs.110).aspx).

You've mentioned you don't, so I think you want this:

```
modelBuilder
  .Entity<Article>
  .HasMany(a => a.RelatedArticles)
  .WithMany()
  .Map(a => a.ToTable("RelatedArticles");
```

Comment: This attribute would be used on a class, but I don't have a class for RelatedArticles. Just a field inside the Article class that contains a List or Articles. I'll update the question with this information.

Comment: I wanted to accept your response but D Stanley fixed the issue I was then getting with mapping the table columns. I really appreciate your help with this regardless. Thanks.